# Collapsible Table of Contents sidebar in Sphinx rtd theme

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, read-the-docs, tableofcontents

I am using Sphinx to document my python code, I've opted to use the built in sphinx_rtd_theme (read the docs theme) as [shown in](http://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.org/en/latest/demo.html)

My documentation is purely local, it is in no way connected to the internet, it looks fine except that in the demo the table of contents(sidebar) expands and collapses when you hit the [+] or [-] symbols. Mine does not, actually it does expand on the first click, subsequent clicks open up the path to the index.html folder in windows explorer. Double clicking does the same.
My question is how can I prevent this behaviour and make my table of contents work just as in  the demo with a nicely expandable/collapsible TOC.
Is it a setting in the conf.py file?

I did read the docs from the sphinx website which points to themeing options, but they only seem to apply to the classic theme. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Quite a similar issue, just that in my case all sections are expanded by default and I want at least some of them to be collapsed. Ironically Sphinx documentation lacks in this area.